# creating an Image from SVG on the server using asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create an image from an svg that I pass into my controller from the client side.

the svg is being passed in thourgh a posted form's hidden input.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult GetChartImage(string svgString)
{
    byte[] imageBytes;

    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(svgString);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(stream);
        var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw();
        bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return File(new MemoryStream(imageBytes), "image/png");
}
```

the problem is that when the process finishes the new webpage that was opened as a result of posting the form, doesn't show the produced image:

[image]

Comment: your image is illegible

Comment: What is the code in the View

Comment: there is no code in the view, the form is posted to an action and a new window opens up.

Comment: Somewhere in the view you set the src for the img?

Comment: no its just returning bytes " return File(new MemoryStream(imageBytes), "image/png");"

Comment: no View.. ok. Return FileContentResult instead of File

Comment: its the same, no image is displayed

Comment: Return an byte[] not Memorystream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a version that is using GET

MyController:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileContentResult GetEmployeeImage()
{
    byte[] image = byteArrayFromImage;

    return new FileContentResult(image , "image/jpeg");
}
```

View:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetEmployeeImage", "MyController")" alt="avatar" />
```